# Grouping in MySQL with sequence numbers and blanks for repeating values

Tags: mysql, sql, report

I want to create report from resource table like this

```
docid|col5 |  item     | qty | price |
------------------------------------------
doc1 |  a  |   item1   | 4   | 100   | 
doc1 |  a  |   item2   | 5   | 20    |
doc2 |  a  |   item3   | 10  | 20    |
doc2 |  a  |   item4   | 11  | 20    |
```

to be like this

```
no | docid  |   item    | qt  | price |
------------------------------------------
1  |  doc1  |   item1   | 4   | 100   |
   |        |   item2   | 5   | 20    |
2  |  doc2  |   item3   | 10  | 20    |
   |        |   item4   | 11  | 20    |
```

anyone can help me

Comment: Where is "no" coming from? Is that a column in your database or an arbitrary number you wish to define in the results?

Comment: I think "no" is a sequence number.  My answer below provides one way to do that in MySql

Answer (score 1):

The query below will do what you want. It has three special-ish features.

1. First, it uses the incrementing `@docIdNumber` user variable to
   generate sequence numbers (1,2) to accompany (doc1,doc2).  This is
   one way to do this in MySQL.
2. Second, it uses the `@prevDocId` user variable to track whether an item
   is still the same as it was on the previous row.  If it is, it
   prints '', not the value.
3. Finally, note the unusual use of INNER JOINs to initialize the user
   variables to 0 or ''.  This is a trick to get those
   variables initialized.  That's all it does.

The whole thing is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99899/61, if you want to experiment.

```
SELECT 
  IF(t.docid=@prevDocId,'',number) as number,
  IF(t.docid=@prevDocId,'',@prevDocId:=t.docid) AS docid,
  item,qty,price
FROM
( 
  SELECT DISTINCT docid,item,qty,price
  FROM theTable
  ORDER BY docid
) AS t
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT @docIdNumber := @docIdNumber + 1 as number, docid
  FROM
  (
    SELECT docid
    FROM theTable
    GROUP BY docid
  ) t
  INNER JOIN (SELECT @docIdNumber := 0) as initializerOnly1
) docIdNumbers ON t.docid = docIdNumbers.docid
INNER JOIN (SELECT @prevDocId := '') as initializerOnly2
```